# lvm-managed gpt partition: partition length exceeds the loop-partition-table-imposed maximum

Tags: lvm, gpt, parted

CentOS 6.4

/dev/sdb is a hardware raid.

I'm getting this error reported from 'parted -l':

```
<snip>

Model: JetStor JetStor -VOL#000 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 39.0TB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 1      1049kB  39.0TB  39.0TB               primary


Error: partition length of 6601834496 sectors exceeds the                 
loop-partition-table-imposed maximum of 4294967295

<snip>
```

BTW, I'm assuming the error message above belongs to the /dev/sdb, and not to the next device listed by parted.

There's another ServerFault post about this parted error but it's not helping me.

The device /dev/sdb is managed by lvm, comprising a single volume group and split into two logical volumes, xfs-formatted. Each volume is mounted and working properly as far as I can tell, with quite a bit of use over the past few weeks.

```
lvm> pvs
  PV         VG         Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree  
  /dev/sdb1  vg_jet716s lvm2 a--   35.47t 429.57g
lvm> vgs
  VG         #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree  
  vg_jet716s   1   2   0 wz--n-  35.47t 429.57g
lvm> lvs
  LV           VG         Attr      LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  lv_jet716s_1 vg_jet716s -wi-ao--- 31.98t                                             
  lv_jet716s_2 vg_jet716s -wi-ao---  3.07t
```

I just saw the above error message. Previously I must have printed the partition stats directly, because if I do that I get no error reported:

```
[root@cfile ~]# parted /dev/sdb print
Model: JetStor JetStor -VOL#000 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 39.0TB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 1      1049kB  39.0TB  39.0TB               primary
```

I created the gpt partition like so in parted, from my notes:

```
mklabel gpt
mkpart (then, primary - xfs - 0% - 100%)
align-check opt 1
```

I've grown each of the two volumes a couple times already, each by about 10% of original size.

One post I found elsewhere thought this error might be a parted bug and nothing to worry about. Any thoughts here? Thanks!

-Michael

Answer (score 0):

This is a snippet from a team email about this problem:
Redhat told me that parted has limitation of 2TB loop table for LV although underneath is GPT table, and Redhat will have fix in v6.5.

Comment: Thanks. So is it a problem that effects the stability or behavior of the volume, or just a reporting bug? I figure since it's a team email there's no link to the conversation for my records?